# How to not to delete if record exists as a foreign in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables. If I delete a record from table1 then first query should check if it's pk exists as a foreign key in table2 then it should not delete the record else it should.

I used this but throwing syntax error

```
DELETE FROM Setup.IncentivesDetail
INNER JOIN Employee.IncentivesDetail ON Setup.IncentivesDetail.IncentivesDetailID = Employee.IncentivesDetail.IncentiveDetail_ID
WHERE Setup.IncentivesDetail.IncentivesDetailID= @IncentivesDetailID
    AND Employee.IncentivesDetail.IncentiveDetail_ID= @IncentivesDetailID
```

UPDATE:

Based on the answers below I have done this, is it correct ?

```
If Not Exists(Select * from Employee.IncentivesDetail where IncentivesDetail.IncentiveDetail_ID= @IncentivesDetailID)
        Begin
            Delete from Setup.IncentivesDetail
            WHERE Setup.IncentivesDetail.IncentivesDetailID= @IncentivesDetailID
        End
        Else
        Begin
            RAISERROR('Record cannot be deleted because assigned to an employee',16,1) 
            RETURN  
        End
```

Comment: Why don't you define a foreign key constraint? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx

Comment: then you can't delete it if it's still referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
DELETE FROM Setup.IncentivesDetail
WHERE Setup.IncentivesDetail.IncentivesDetailID= @IncentivesDetailID
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Employee.IncentivesDetail WHERE IncentiveDetail_ID= @IncentivesDetailID)
```

But I must admit, this *smells* a bit... Are you doing a clean up or ist this something you are doing regularely?

Comment: regularly i do this and have to

Comment: See the scenario is that I have to delete a record from Table1 but if it exists as a foreign in table2 then it should not be delete else it should be.

Comment: @Quoran, If there is a FK defined, you **cannot** delete this. There will be an error. If you want to avoid this error, you might go this way, but I think it would be cleaner first to check and then to delete. Otherwise you have a running script but no return if there was something deleted or not...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, based on your answer I have done this, please check 

If Not Exists(Select * from Employee.IncentivesDetail where IncentivesDetail.IncentiveDetail_ID= @IncentivesDetailID)
  Begin
   Delete from Setup.IncentivesDetail
   WHERE Setup.IncentivesDetail.IncentivesDetailID= @IncentivesDetailID
  End
  Else
  Begin
   RAISERROR('Record cannot be deleted because assigned to an employee',16,1) 
      RETURN  
  End

Comment: @Quoran, This seems to be correct, but: You are re-inventing the wheel. This is exactly the thing a foreign key is meant to do automatically... If you like my answer please vote it up, if it solved your issue please tick the acceptance, thx!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the definition of the foreign key constraint.
If you already have a foreign key between these tables, make sure it's **not** marked as `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
If it is, you should delete it and re-create it without that `ON DELETE CASCADE` see [this link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175493.aspx#TsqlProcedure) for details.
If you don't already have a foreign key constraint, you need to create one:

```
ALTER TABLE Setup.IncentivesDetail 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Setup_IncentivesDetail_IncentivesDetailID FOREIGN KEY (IncentivesDetailID) 
    REFERENCES Employee.IncentivesDetail (IncentiveDetail_ID ) 
;
```